# Can the ipython notebook YouTubeVideo class play from time offset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

If I am embedding a youtube video clip into an iPython notebook:

```
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
YouTubeVideo("Pi9NpxAvYSs")
```

Is there a way I can embed this such that it would play from a specific time? So 1:47:03 - 1 hour, 47 minutes and 3 seconds?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update

Now you can use [any parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#parameter-subheader) you like from the youtube player:

```
from datetime import timedelta

start=int(timedelta(hours=1, minutes=46, seconds=40).total_seconds())

YouTubeVideo("Pi9NpxAvYSs", start=start, autoplay=1, theme="light", color="red")
```

---

### Old answer

The [current implementation](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/lib/display.py) doesn't allow it, but it's pretty easy to extend:

```
from datetime import timedelta

class YouTubeVideo(object):
    def __init__(self, id, width=400, height=300, start=timedelta()):
        self.id = id
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.start = start.total_seconds()

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return """
            <iframe
                width="%i"
                height="%i"
                src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/%s?start=%i"
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen
            ></iframe>
        """%(self.width, self.height, self.id, self.start)
```

And voilà:

```
YouTubeVideo("Pi9NpxAvYSs", start=timedelta(hours=1, minutes=47, seconds=3))
```

Now we could send a pull request :)

Comment: Ah - of course, it is html it outputs, and not a lot around the video. And yes - I think a pull request would be a neat way to wrap it up.

Comment: Done - with attribution to this SO page.

Comment: It turned out a little different - we went with a system of converting additional kwargs to params from the youtube API (documented in the display.YoutubeVideo class). It means you have to convert your times via timedelta external to the youtube class, but it means you can use any parameter you like from the youtube player.

Comment: @DannyStaple I think it's much better now! In this way you can use _any_ player parameter you like. Great work!